# Can a pointer be marshalled to an array when passing a struct?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

In the below example, the `dataArray` defined in C++ works if defined as an array, but not as a pointer (Just turns out garbage data). Is there another way to marshal the C# array so that it reads the pointer in as an array?

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct CSharpFoo{
    int alpha;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5]
    public int[] dataArray;
    int beta;
}
```

C++

```
struct CPPFoo{
    int alpha;
    //int* dataArray; //Doesn't work, even though initialized to an array elsewhere
    int dataArray[5];
    int beta;
}
```

Being passed through a function like this
C#

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public extern static bool InitializeDLL([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ResultCallback callbackPointer);
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void ResultCallback(CSharpFoo value);
```

C++

```
//Callback
typedef void(__stdcall * ResultCallback)(CPPFoo);
__declspec(dllexport) bool InitializeDLL(ResultCallback callback);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit::
Because "initialized to an array elsewhere" wasn't clear:

```
CPPFoo(int dummy){ //Constructor
    alpha = 32;
    dataArray = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        dataArray[i] = i;
    }
    beta = 13;
}
//dataArray C++ {0,1,2,3,4}
//alpha C# 32
//dataArray C# {Total random garbage} (dataArray[3] is 13!)
//beta C# 0
```

PS, the CPPFoo struct is a complex struct that comes from a DLL, so I cannot change it. For now, to get things working, I copy it to a more appropriate array like in NonCreature0714's answer, but this results in all of the data being copied--twice. It's this double copy that I'm trying to avoid.

Another edit:
While it seems that for a struct containing a single array the values get passed properly, for a complex struct, garbage gets thrown in.
I have updated the code to reflect a more complex struct!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Garbage data. Will edit now

Comment: `int* dataArray;`  -- To us, it is garbage data.  We have no idea what this pointer points to, as it is uninitialized.  Maybe what you thought you set this to is a local variable (thus no longer exists).

Comment: Initialized to an array elsewhere?  I receive it from a separate DLL and the documentation refers to it as a pointer to an array.

Comment: I believe it will still fail even if you declare it 'int* dataArray = new int[5]'

Comment: `int* dataArray = new int[5]`.  This creates dynamically an *uninitialized* array of 5 ints.  So how do you know if it works if you don't set the elements to anything?

Comment: Sorry, was giving an example. I know for sure that the DLL is returning valid data and that the data is completely fine up until the point of crossing from C++ to C#.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Sorry, I'm using DllImport, it just wasn't in the dummy code. I'll add it now

Comment: Why not simply use `vector<int> dataArray;` and pass a reference to the vector?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 beacuse its not just 1 array, its a complex struct, containing data received from a DLL (so I can't change it)

Comment: @Mars oh, gotcha, that wasn’t clear to me. That’s an important detail, can you edit your answer to state that?

Answer (score 1):

I did a couple of tests on my local machine, as far as I understood your code. I had no problems with the following code

c# side

```
struct Foo
{
    public int alpha;

    public IntPtr Data;

    public int beta;

    public void GetData(ref int[] buffer,int length)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(Data,buffer,0,length);
    }

}
```

class Program
    {

```
    [DllImport("MyPtr.dll",EntryPoint = "InitializeDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool InitializeDLL([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]ResultCallback callbackPointer);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void ResultCallback(ref Foo value);

    static void CallBackMe(ref Foo value)
    {
        var buffer = new int[5];
        value.GetData(ref buffer,buffer.Length);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeDLL(CallBackMe);
    }
}
```

C++ side

```
struct CPPFoo {
    int* dataArrayPtr;
    CPPFoo()
    {
        dataArrayPtr = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dataArrayPtr[i] = i;
        }
    }
};

typedef void(__stdcall * ResultCallback)(CPPFoo);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool InitializeDLL(ResultCallback callback)
{
    CPPFoo f;
    callback(f);
    return true;
}
```

Code in action
[image]

Comment: Thats interesting! But it didn't work. Hang on while I update the question

Comment: @Mars, Could you please tell me what didnt work exactly? I have this code working without any problems

Comment: I updated the code. Please try again with the more complex struct :)

Comment: @Mars, yeah array became garbage values

Comment: @Mars, Hey there I updated my answer with a working copy

Comment: Hmm... is there a reason why Foo became a reference?

Comment: @Mars, you may be right there may be slightly differrence. I hastily tested before leaving office. But screen shot is the latest code and it works. There is no specific reason I made it into reference. Personal preference, I pass as ref when Pinvoking. With or without ref works

Comment: I think using IntPtr will allow me to at least avoid copying things once on the C++ side and then again when crossing from C++ to C#, but for now, things are roughly working, so the project has moved on. I:m also heading out of the office soon, so I'll check it out later!

Comment: @Mars,then お疲れ様です

Comment: お疲れ様です！To you to!

Comment: By the way, you scared the hell out of me speaking Japanese suddenly haha

Comment: @Mars, I just clicked on your profile, hoping to get some info about where you live because you said you were leaving the office as I was leaving  turns out we are both in Japan

Answer (score 0):

My experience in C# is very limited but it seems that it works with *int dataArray[5];* because the code agrees to the type of CSharpFoo and CPPFoo.  The size of both is five ints.  When you change the type to a pointer then one is the size of five ints and the other is a single pointer which would be less then five ints.

Most likely passing a dynamically sized array will need a size and to get a pointer you may need to do something with unsafe code but I don't write in C# so that is just a guess.

```
struct CPPFoo {
    int* dataArray = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Passing it as a fixed size array isn't impossible, but it means copying the data twice, which is less than ideal

Comment: I was thinking you could pass the address of the original array which is why I was thinking of the C# unsafe block.  Can the address be assigned and the size of the array.  Then the C++ code can push it into a vector<int> type.  I am guessing a little to be honest.

I do think there needs to be a copy just for the sake of ownership.  If no copy is made then there must be some guarantee that the array of ints remains until the C++ code no longer references it.

Comment: An option to consider, but currently `unsafe` is not enabled and i don't know that the client will allow it

Comment: would something like int[] = new int[size];

Comment: Sorry, i hit enter on the last comment before I was ready.

I think the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5] may be what needs to be changed.  Can something like the following work in C#?  What happens without the marshal...?

public struct CSharpFoo{
    public int[] dataArray;
    public int dataSize;
}

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I tried helping but I think I made things worse.  I am new to this posting stuff.

Comment: The code would be easier to understand if you "Edit" your answer instead :)

Comment: But for the record, without the marshal the app crashes!

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector.

```
#include <vector>

struct CPPFoo {
    std::vector<int> dataArray;
};
```

Vector is more readable and more safe. It only *slighty* increases the size of the code, and is only slightly slower than using a primitive array. You also don’t need to worry about keeping around a variable for size, and updating it every time it’s changes.